# batch script find folder(LAST NAME FIRST) based on file name(LAST NAME FIRST NAME)

Tags: batch-file

I'm using Windows 7.

I have hundreds of files that need to be moved to their respective folders. Here's an example file name:

File name: "SMITH John Sign On Sheet"

The folders, unfortunately are not named just with their LAST NAME and First Name only. For example:

Folder name: SMITH John Completed.

I've created a batch script(thanks to other Q&As here) that can move files if the folder name was "LAST Name and First name" only, but need help if the folder names have extra words after the first name. Any suggestion would be great.

Comment: Could you post the batch file you made.

Comment: I posted it in my answer below. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can extract specific parts of strings using a for loop:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%a in ("!placefilenameshere!") do (
set lastname=%%a
set firstname=%%b
)
```

With another for loop you can work yourself through (sub-)directories:

```
set parentdir="C:\foo\bar"
REM you can use network paths as well!
pushd !parentdir!
for /r %%g in (.) do (

  set dirname=%%g
  set dirsave=%%g
  for /L %%I in (1,1,20) do set dirname=!dirname:*\=!

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%m in ("!dirname!") do (
set lastdir=%%m
set firstdir=%%n
)

  if /i "x!lastdir! !firstdir!"=="x!lastname! !firstname!" (
      popd
      REM MOVE FILES TO DIRSAVE
      pushd !parentdir!
  )
)
```

Explanation:
With the first block you extract the first two words from the filename, you would place in the first brackets of the loop as a variable for example.
So the last- and firstname are saved in the two variables `lastname` and `firstname`.
Change the variable `parentdir` to the path where all your folders are placed where you want to place the files.
The second loop goes through the folders in the directory you specified above and saves the directory path in two variables. One to use later `datsave` and one to check if the correct directory is found `datname`.
The small loop in there deletes all the parent directory strings from the path variable and then gets the first two words from that as well.

Example:
`C:\some\long\path\goes here` would first be shortened to `goes here` and then separated to `lastdir = goes` and `firstdir = here`.

Last step is to check if the first two words fomr the directory and from the filename are the same (not case-sensitive). In that you would place the command to move the files to the path `dirsave` which is the saved full path (see above).

Put all that into another loop that goes through the filenames and it should work.

However, this is untested... Someone more experienced might want to look over this first before somethings goes wrong...

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*" '
 ) DO (
 SET "destsubdir="
 CALL :finddest %%a
 IF DEFINED destsubdir (CALL :transfer "%%a"
 ) ELSE (
  ECHO %%a: No unique subdir found
 )
)

GOTO :EOF

:transfer
ECHO(MOVE "%sourcedir%\%~1" "%destdir%\%destsubdir%\"
GOTO :eof

:finddest
:: get the next subdir part
SET "subdirfound=%1"
:: If there are no more, exit - unique not found
IF NOT DEFINED subdirfound GOTO nouniquefound
:: see whether there is exactly one destination subdir with
:: the accumulated subdirname so far
IF DEFINED destsubdir (
 SET "accumsubdir=%destsubdir% %1"
) ELSE (
 REM force at least 2 names
 SET "destsubdir=%1"&shift&GOTO finddest
)
shift
SET "subdirfound="
FOR /f "delims=" %%d IN ('dir /b/ad "%destdir%\%accumsubdir%*" 2^>nul') DO (
 rem if subdirfound is already set, 2 or more exist
 IF DEFINED subdirfound SET "destsubdir=%accumsubdir%"&GOTO finddest
 rem otherwise, record destination subdirectory to use
 SET "subdirfound=%%d"
)

:: none are found or unique has been found - now in subdirfound
:nouniquefound
SET "destsubdir=%subdirfound%"
IF NOT DEFINED destsubdir GOTO :EOF
GOTO :eof
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

Suppose the source directory is:

```
 Volume in drive U has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is BDA0-0000

 Directory of u:\sourcedir

19/09/2016  23:06                 0 q1234
19/09/2016  23:06                 0 Smith John Sign on sheet
19/09/2016  23:06                 0 Robinson Bill Sign on sheet
19/09/2016  23:06                 0 Robinson Bill expenses
19/09/2016  23:06                 0 Robinson George expenses
19/09/2016  23:06                 0 Robinson Fred expenses
19/09/2016  23:06                 0 Jones George expenses
19/09/2016  23:06                 0 von Richthofen Manfred expenses
19/09/2016  23:06                 0 von Richthofen Manfred timesheet
               9 File(s)              0 bytes
```

And the destination directory is

```
 Volume in drive U has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is BDA0-0000

 Directory of u:\destdir

19/09/2016  23:06    <DIR>          .
19/09/2016  23:06    <DIR>          ..
19/09/2016  23:06    <DIR>          Smith John data
19/09/2016  23:06    <DIR>          Robinson Bill data
19/09/2016  23:06    <DIR>          Jones George data
19/09/2016  23:06    <DIR>          von Richthofen Manfred data
19/09/2016  23:06    <DIR>          von Richthofen Lothar data
19/09/2016  23:06    <DIR>          q1234
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
```

Then running this batch produces

```
q1234: No unique subdir found
MOVE "U:\sourcedir\Smith John Sign on sheet" "U:\destdir\Smith John data\"
MOVE "U:\sourcedir\Robinson Bill Sign on sheet" "U:\destdir\Robinson Bill data\"
MOVE "U:\sourcedir\Robinson Bill expenses" "U:\destdir\Robinson Bill data\"
Robinson George expenses: No unique subdir found
Robinson Fred expenses: No unique subdir found
MOVE "U:\sourcedir\Jones George expenses" "U:\destdir\Jones George data\"
MOVE "U:\sourcedir\von Richthofen Manfred expenses" "U:\destdir\von Richthofen Manfred data\"
MOVE "U:\sourcedir\von Richthofen Manfred timesheet" "U:\destdir\von Richthofen Manfred data\"
```

The `for` loop using `%%a` assigns each filename in turn to `%%a`, initialises `destsubdir` and executes `:finddest` using the filename as an argument.

`:finddest` will either assign the target directoryname to `destsubdir` or will return with `destsubdir` cleared, indicating an error. `if defined` detects the difference and either runs `:transfer` to move the file (currently simply `echo`es the proposed `move`) or reports it couldn't find a unique subdirectoryname.

`:finddest` will set the first name into `destsubdir` and `shift` so that the next name is `%1`

If we run out of names, we haven't found a unique subdirectory name, so we exit with `destsubdir` empty. This would be the case for `q1234` because there is no second name.

We then append the next name to `destsubdir` to form `accumsubdir` and `shift` to remove the name just used.

Then set `subdirfound` to *nothing* ready for the next step.

Each directoryname matching the accumulated subdirectory is assigned to `%%d`. If `subdirfound` is already set, then there are 2 or more matching names, so back to `finddest` to accumulate the next name, etc.

If the `for` loop completes, then either there is exactly one destination subdirectory name found (`subdirfound` contains its name) or there are none (`subdirfound` still empty). Either way, we can assign `destsubdir` to that value, and exit the subroutine.

Consequently, the file will be transferred to the for instance `von Richthofen Manfred` using 3 names since `von Richthofen` is not unique. This can be used to distinguish between John A Smith and John B. Smith or between van der Waals Johannes and van der Waals Jacobus for instance.